# How do I use node.js in index.html without nodeIntegration [electron]

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm starting out to build a new electron app, but it needs to use certain node.js functions in the html page. I know that setting `nodeIntegration: true` is not secure, and I know that I can use `preload.js` somehow, but I can't find out how. Any and all help will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

P.S. Are there any circumstances in which `nodeIntegration: true` *is* safe, because otherwise why would they have it?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I want my HTML in `data/screens/index.html`, and my `index.html`'s javascript in `data/screens/js/index.js`, and, if possible, to still be able to use things like `document.innerHTML` for example. I don't know if it's possible, but I'll never find out if I don't ask. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of preload argument in webPreferences while creating the main BrowserWindow.
In the main.js,

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
```

In the preload.js

```
   window.notify= function notify(msg) {
   return require('node-notifier').notify(msg);
   };
```

OR

Try using remote module of electron (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote)

OR

Access the module in main process, call the functions for the expected outcome and send back the result to renderer process using IPC.